# Is the Dikin Ellipsoid actually a ball?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, sampling

I have the inequality (row wise): $Ax \leq b$

The Dikin ellipsoid centered at $x_0$ with radius $r$ is:

$$\{z \quad | \quad (z-x_0)^T(z-x_0) \leq \frac{r^2}{H(x_0)}\}$$

where,

$$H(x_0) = \sum \frac{a_i * a_i^T}{(b_i - a_ix_0)^2}$$

$a_i$ is the $i^{th}$ row of $A$. $b_i$ is the $i^{th}$ element of $b$.

**this seems like a ball to me, with radius $\frac{r}{\sqrt{H(x_0)}}$**

Some references for the Dikin Ellipsoid:

http://stanford.edu/class/ee364b/lectures/dikin_slides.pdf
http://ie.technion.ac.il/~ehazan/courses/LPpoly12/dan.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the slides you provided, I think you have misunderstood the definition.  In the Preliminaries section I see the definition:
$$\{z \quad | \quad (z-x_0)^TH_{x_0}(z-x_0) \leq r^2\}$$
where $H_{x_0}$ is defined by 
$$H_{x_0} = \sum \frac{a_i^T * a_i}{(b_i - a_ix_0)^2}$$
where $a_i$ are row vectors of the matrix $A$.

However, $H_{x_0}$ is not a constant.  Instead, it is a matrix acting on the vector $(z - x_0)$ in the definition of the ellipse above.  You can see that it is a matrix because it is a sum of multiplications of the form $a_i^T * a_i$ which are matrices.

Comment: but $a_i$ is a row vector, so $a_i * a_i^T$ should be a scalar (?). Also, if it were a vector, it doesn't make sense to me to divide a matrix by a matrix.

Comment: @AndyYao - the $a_i$ are column vectors of the matrix $A$.  See pg. 3 of 18 of dan.pdf you linked.  The denominator is a number.  If $b_i$ are real, then you are looking at the difference between it and the inner product of $a_i$ and $x_0$.

Comment: Let's say A is $m \times n$, and b is $m \times 1$. If $a_i$ were the columns of $A$, then $a_i^T$ would be $1 \times m$. I cannot take an inner product of a $1 \times m$ with a $n \times 1$ vector $x$.

Comment: @AndyYao You are quite right.  And that means that his formula on $pg. 3$ really isn't right.  I amended my answer to use row vectors.  Either way, take a look at the proof on pg.3.  There you can see what $\quad (z-x_0)^TH_{x_0}(z-x_0)$ evaluates too.  It certainly is not treating that $H_{x_0}$ as a number.

Comment: hmmm. I think you're right. I'll try to look more closely into what the formula is doing. Thanks a lot for your suggestions!

Comment: Thanks a lot. You're right. $H(x_0)$ is indeed an invertible operator. I took a look at some other paper. As you said, the slides are confusing and probably contain typos.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it is indeed a ball in $\mathbb R^n$ with the usual Euclidean norm  with the radius you say and a center at $x_0$.

Comment: thank you. do you have any idea why it's called an ellipsoid then...this seems rather confusing? I've also seen some generic plots that don't resemble a ball..